# better way to assign variable percentage change calculated

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 variables in my PL/SQL procedure that get the counts.
using those values I am calculating the percentage change between two tables. This is how I am doing it:

```
SELECT (
         decode(original_count,
                0,
                to_number(0),
                ((todays_count - original_count)/original_count)
                )
       ) 
  INTO percentage_change 
  FROM DUAL;
```

I was wondering if there is a way to do it by using `:=` assignment
something like:

```
percentage_change := (decode(original_count,
                             0,
                             to_number(0),
                             ((todays_count - original_count)/original_count)
                             )
                      )
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Yes, you can. Use `case` expression instead of `decode()`(can be used only in a DML statement) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the case construct:

```
percentage_change := case when original_count=0 then 0
                         else (todays_count - original_count)/original_count end;
```